# Sending sigstop and sigcont to docker containers

Tags: docker

I am attempting to send `SIGSTOP`, and then later, `SIGKILL` to a container. This line leads me to believe that it will behave as I expect: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/5948#issuecomment-43684471

However, it is going ahead and actually removing the containers. The commands are:

```
docker kill -s STOP container
docker kill -s CONT container
```

(Equivalent through the dockerode API I am using, but I just went to command line when that wasn't working). Is there some missing options I'm missing?

Comment: was the container created with the [`--rm`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/run/) option

Answer (score 1):

I think you're actually looking for the commands `docker pause` and `docker unpause`. Using the `STOP` signal is likely to be error-prone and dependent on how the process handles the signal.

I guess what's happening in this case is that Docker thinks the process has terminated and stops the container (it shouldn't be removed however, you can restart it with `docker start`).